# linking error with Visual studio different versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I get this error when I run my sln with Visual studio 2005version 8.0.50727.42 ,.NET framework version 2.0.50727 .

**error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol**
but I don't get the error while running the same sln through Visual Studio 2005 with .NET framework of little higher version.

I reinstalled the previous version mentioned above.but still having the same linking errors.

Requirement is to build the code with the first version mentioned above.
Please suggest way ot.

Note: the project properties are set the same while building the code with two different version mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [/VERBOSE flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for your linker (Note: Make sure that you set it for the linker). Then look through all included libraries and verify that the one that contains the symbol in question is linked properly.

EDIT: Also note that you will not get a proper warning when linking (or rather failing to link) against 64-bit libraries in a 32-bit project.